# SQL - Filter by CONSTRAINT_TYPE

Tags: sql, oracle, filter, oracle19c

I need the following query to only return columns with a UNIQUE constraint:

```
SELECT col.owner as schema_name,
       col.table_name,
       column_name,
       data_type,
       data_precision
FROM sys.dba_tab_cols col
JOIN sys.dba_tables tab on col.owner = tab.owner
     and col.table_name = tab.table_name
WHERE data_type in ('NUMBER','BINARY_FLOAT', 'BINARY_DOUBLE','FLOAT')
      and data_precision IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY col.owner,
         col.table_name,
         column_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would require join with yet two tables, the ones that contains info about constraints and columns involved.

I restricted owners to only one; you'll probably want to do the opposite - **remove** users you aren't interested in, such as SYS, SYSTEM, etc.

```
SQL> select tab.owner as schema_name,
  2    tab.table_Name,
  3    col.column_name,
  4    col.data_type,
  5    col.data_precision,
  6    con.constraint_type
  7  from dba_tables tab join dba_tab_cols col on tab.owner = col.owner
  8                                           and tab.table_name = col.table_name
  9                      join dba_constraints con on con.owner = tab.owner
 10                                              and con.table_name = tab.table_name
 11                      join dba_cons_columns ccol on ccol.owner = con.owner
 12                                                and ccol.table_name = con.table_name
 13                                                and ccol.column_name = col.column_name
 14                                                and ccol.constraint_name = con.constraint_name
 15  where tab.owner in ('SCOTT')
 16    and col.data_type in ('NUMBER', 'BINARY_FLOAT', 'BINARY_DOUBLE', 'FLOAT')
 17    and con.constraint_type = 'U'
 18  order by tab.owner, tab.table_name, col.column_name;

SCHEMA_NAME TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE       DATA_PRECISION CONSTRAINT_TYPE
----------- ----------- ----------- --------------- -------------- ---------------
SCOTT       TEMP_UNI    ID          NUMBER                         U
SCOTT       TEST2       ID          NUMBER                         U
SCOTT       TEST2       NAME        BINARY_FLOAT                   U

SQL>
```